# Laravel change Connection for Notifications table

Tags: notifications, database-connection, laravel-5.3

I am implementing Laravel 5.3 Notifications at the moment which is working very nice.

At the moment I am using 'email' as a notifications channel but I want to add 'database' too. I am using different databases/connections for languages and want to store the notifications in a central database / Connection.

**How do I use a different database connection for notifications?**

I already tried creating a Notifications model but that did not work:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Notifications extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'system';
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Hackish solution. But tried and tested on a MongoDB connection.

What needs to be modified;

1. The `Notifiable` trait
2. The `DatabaseNotification` model
3. Optionally (nothing changes if you are using mysql) modify the `HasNotifications` trait
4. Modify the `DatabaseNotificationCollection`.Again this is useful for a non-mysql connection

### Step One : Create a custom `Notifiable` Trait

Copy the contents from `Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable` and create a new file in your custom path...say `App\Overrides\Notifications\Notifiable`.

Your file will feature two changes...the namespace and you have to load the `RoutesNotifications` trait since we are not copying it over.

```
<?php

namespace App\Overrides\Notifications;

use use Illuminate\Notifications\RoutesNotifications;

trait Notifiable{
 //The rest of the code remains
}
```

### Step Two : Create a custom `DatabaseNotification` model

Follow the same procedure as above and copy the contents of the `Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification` file to the custom path that we created above...`App\Overrides\Notification\DatabaseNotification`

This is a standard Eloquent model and the connection change actually happens here

```
<?php

namespace App\Overrides\Notification;

//Use this if on mongodb.otherwise use to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotificationCollection;

class DatabaseNotification extends Model
{
  protected $connection = 'YOUR_CONNECTION_NAME_GOES HERE'; 
}
```

As of this point this should work if you are on a mysql connection.

To try this out change the `Notifiable` trait on the user model to use `App\Overrides\Notifications\Notifiable`. The notifications will use the connection you specified.

Users of MongoDB will have to take extra steps since the [most popular driver](http://jenssegers.be/projects/laravel-mongodb) I know of does not yet [support `MorphMany` relations](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/536) which are put to use for Laravel notifications.

Since that is not the asked question we leave it at that :-)

Comment: And do not forget to also use the ``HasDatabaseNotification`` and in it, set your custom ``DatabaseNotification`` Model, otherwise, it will not work ;)

Answer (score 3):

On Laravel 5.7 based on @Bernard answer

User.php

```
<?php

namespace App;

// implement the override Notifiable trait
use App\Traits\Override\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
}
```

Notifiable.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits\Override;

use Illuminate\Notifications\RoutesNotifications;

trait Notifiable
{
    use HasDatabaseNotifications, RoutesNotifications;
}
```

HasDatabaseNotifications.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits\Override;

use App\Models\Override\MultiConnectionDatabaseNotification;

trait HasDatabaseNotifications
{
    /**
     * Get the entity's notifications.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany
     */
    public function notifications()
    {
        return $this->morphMany(MultiConnectionDatabaseNotification::class, 'notifiable')->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
    }

    /**
     * Get the entity's read notifications.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
     */
    public function readNotifications()
    {
        return $this->notifications()->whereNotNull('read_at');
    }

    /**
     * Get the entity's unread notifications.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
     */
    public function unreadNotifications()
    {
        return $this->notifications()->whereNull('read_at');
    }
}
```

MultiConnectionDatabaseNotification.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models\Override;

use Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification as DatabaseNotification;

class MultiConnectionDatabaseNotification extends DatabaseNotification
{
    // set your preferred connection here
    protected $connection = 'oracle';
}
```

Answer (score -2):

It's pretty simple, Just add   `protected $connection = 'YOUR CONNECTION NAME';` at `Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification`

That's all and it will work :)

You don't need to create new models if you are going to use one notification table with same connection.

My code will works if ur using different connection for USER model.

Comment: You should never, ever change the core files in any framework.