# Laravel Notifications with custom connection

Tags: php, laravel

in my `Laravel` app I want to use the *native* [notifications system](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/notifications), provided by `Laravel` itself. Besides mail I want to use the [database channel](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/notifications#database-notifications), but I have to use a custom database connection for the notification records.

Currently I'm using my own **Notification model**:

```php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification as BaseNotification;

class Notification extends BaseNotification
{
    protected $connection = 'team';
}
```

But I was wondering if there's a better way for doing this. I know this isn't specific to the notifications system — I guess it's more of a general `Laravel/PHP` question.

Comment: Maybe this question can help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41521255/laravel-change-connection-for-notifications-table

Comment: Thanks @user931018, i didn't see that question before.